# How do you prove that $\int_{1}^{n}\ln x \,dx \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ln i -\frac{\ln n }{2}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In Upfal's probability textbook Lemma 5.8, he tries to justify
 $\int_{1}^{n}\ln x \,dx \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \ln i -\frac{\ln n }{2}$ with concavity of $\ln x$, I don't quite follow his argument, can someone elaborate?

Comment: Yeah sorry, the integration lower range is off by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concave function $f$ on an interval $[a,a+1]$ satisfies
$$
f(a+x) \ge (1-x)f(a) + x f(a+1)
$$ 
for all $x \in [0,1]$. Integrate this inequality over $x \in [0,1]$ to deduce
$$
\int_a^{a+1} f(x) \ge \frac{f(a) + f(a+1)}{2}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_j^{j+1} \ln x dx \ge \frac{\ln j + \ln (j+1)}{2}
$$
for all $j>0$. Now sum this from $j = 1$ to $j = n-1$, use $\ln 1 = 0$, and perform some simple algebra to obtain
$$
\int_1^n \ln d x \ge \frac{1}{2} \ln 1 + \sum_{j=2}^{n-1} \ln j + \frac{\ln n}{2} = \sum_{j=1}^n \ln j - \frac{\ln n}{2} .
$$